# List issue on iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I have a simple landing page built with Bootstrap 3.

My issue is with the footer. In particular the list of social media links.

On iOS devices (tested on iPhone 4S and iPad Air), the list is displaying vertically (undesired behaviour), while in all other browsers (tested on Samsung phone) the list is displayed horizontally and without style (desired behaviour)

CSS (the relevant bits)

```
/*=========================
  Footer
 ================= */

.footer {
    margin-top:50px;
    display:block;
}
    .footer p {
        font-size: 14px;
margin-top: 10px;

    }
/*section#footer {
    background: #242424;
    margin: 0;
}

section#footer .copyright {
    text-align: center;
}*/

/* footer social icons */
ul.social-network {
    list-style: none !important;
    list-style-type: none !important;
    display: inline;
    margin-left:0 !important;
    padding: 0;
}
ul.social-network li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 5px;
}

/* footer menu */
ul.footer-menu {
    list-style: none !important;
    list-style-type: none !important;
    display: inline;
    margin-left:0 !important;
    padding: 0;
}
ul.footer-menu li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 5px;
}


/* footer social icons */
.social-network a.icoStack:hover {
    background-color: #ffa500;
}
.social-network a.icoFacebook:hover {
    background-color:#3B5998;
}
.social-network a.icoTwitter:hover {
    background-color:#33ccff;
}
.social-network a.icoEmail:hover {
    background-color:#BD3518;
}
.social-network a.icoBlogger:hover {
    background-color:#fb8f3d;
}
.social-network a.icoLinkedin:hover {
    background-color:#007bb7;
}

.social-network a.icoGithub:hover {
    background-color:#60b044;
}

.social-network a.icoStack:hover i, .social-network a.icoFacebook:hover i, .social-network a.icoTwitter:hover i, 
.social-network a.icoEmail:hover i, .social-network a.icoBlogger:hover i, .social-network a.icoLinkedin:hover i, .social-network a.icoGithub:hover i {
    color:#fff;
}
a.socialIcon:hover, .socialHoverClass {
    color:#44BCDD;
}
```

I have added `!important` to `list-style: none` and `list-style-type: none` but it didn't help.

I could do with a pair of fresh eyes to see what I am missing.

Comment: I created a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1qpzkraa/2/. However, - it works fine for me on my iPad. Did not quite understand the "start slider" tho. Edit: I see Alexander posted the answer below.

Comment: @Olen how do you mean you didn't understand it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You issue isn't limited to iOS Safari, it is affecting desktop Safari also. The Safari developer console offers a hint to what the issue is.

> [Warning] Invalid CSS property declaration at: { (soon.css, line 412)

In that general area, we find some syntax errors in the CSS. It appears that other browsers are doing a better job of error-handling the invalid CSS, but Safari is getting tripped up, and the CSS rules below are being dropped.

### Problem CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes InfiniteTurn {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }

    ;
}

@-moz-keyframes InfiniteTurn {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }

    ;
}

@-o-keyframes InfiniteTurn {
    0% {
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }

    ;
}

@-keyframes InfiniteTurn {
    0%;

{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}

100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}

;
}
```

There are a number of extra `;` characters. You don't need to end a `keyframes` declaration with a semi-colon, but the fatal character is in this section.

```
@-keyframes InfiniteTurn {
    0%;

{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

The extra semi-colon in `0%;` appears to be breaking the CSS in Safari. Removing those extra `;`'s should solve your problem.